# Override hover styles for MuiCheckbox

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Currently all my checkboxes have this circle on hover. I want to remove it

[image]

So I went to overrides in MuiTheme:

```
export const MUI_THEME = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCheckbox: {
      root: {
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

But it produce styles which are ignored in regular browser

```
@media (hover: none) {
  .MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary.Mui-checked:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

How can I create overrides without `@media (hover: none)`?
Only way that comes to mind is to create css style with `!important`, but there must be a way in  `createMuiTheme`

Comment: Did you achieve the desired behavior in the development environment but fail at production environment or you fail from the development env?

Comment: did not even tried to build it for prod, should there be a difference? It would be weird

Answer (score 2):

You need to beat that specificity. One technique I use chaining the css classes e.g., `.class.class{...}` even if it means using the same class name

```
export const MUI_THEME = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCheckbox: {
      root: {
        '&$root$root:hover': {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution without overriding at the theme level is just to override in the custom style prop.

```
sx={{
      '&:hover': { background: 'white' },
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on material ui documentation:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "transparent" <-- Note here
    }
  },
  icon: {
    borderRadius: 3,
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    boxShadow:
      "inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(16,22,26,.2), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(16,22,26,.1)",
    backgroundColor: "#f5f8fa",
    backgroundImage:
      "linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.8),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))",
    "$root.Mui-focusVisible &": {
      outline: "2px auto rgba(19,124,189,.6)",
      outlineOffset: 2
    },
    "input:hover ~ &": {
      backgroundColor: "#ebf1f5"
    },
    "input:disabled ~ &": {
      boxShadow: "none",
      background: "rgba(206,217,224,.5)"
    }
  },
  checkedIcon: {
    backgroundColor: "#137cbd",
    backgroundImage:
      "linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))",
    "&:before": {
      display: "block",
      width: 16,
      height: 16,
      backgroundImage:
        "url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath" +
        " fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M12 5c-.28 0-.53.11-.71.29L7 9.59l-2.29-2.3a1.003 " +
        "1.003 0 00-1.42 1.42l3 3c.18.18.43.29.71.29s.53-.11.71-.29l5-5A1.003 1.003 0 0012 5z' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")",
      content: '""'
    },
    "input:hover ~ &": {
      backgroundColor: "#106ba3"
    }
  }
});
```

jsx:

```
<Checkbox
      className={classes.root}
      disableRipple
      color="default"
      checkedIcon={<span className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.checkedIcon)} />}
      icon={<span className={classes.icon} />}
      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "decorative checkbox" }}
      {...props}
    />
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cxztq?file=/demo.js:1628-1921

Comment: thank you! it works, but requires me to add some styling to each checkbox, and I wanted to create a global override in proper place of creating my theme. For my case it's better to use global css override with !important than to add additional styling for every checkbox :(

Answer (score 0):

You might forgot to pass your theme object to the MuiThemeProvider:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={MUI_THEME}>
    <Checkbox />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Here's a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-override-checkbox-background-934hn?file=/src/Components/App.js:562-645

Comment: thank you, but it is not the case (if you paid attention, the checkbox is already not of default mui colors, so I've attached the provider)

Comment: Hi @KaterinaPavlenko, please check the demo, I think it works as expected.